# Parsing a strangely formatted DateTime. Anyone fancy stepping up?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse a datestamp (that I got from Twitter) but am receiving errors. here's the datestamp:

> Fri, 27 Aug 2010 22:00:07 +0000

Here's my code:

> DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss +ffff", new CultureInfo("en-US"))

and here's my error:

> System.FormatException was unhandled
>     Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Anyone fancy taking that on? To make it easy I've provided the code below for a console app that exhibits the problem.

Thanks
Jamie

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string MyDateValue = "Fri, 27 Aug 2010 22:00:07 +0000";
        var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss +ffff", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone that spotted it should have been yyyy not YYYY. Feel rather embarrassed now...slinking off back to a quiet corner ... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The year specifier is `yyyy`, not `YYYY`:

```
string MyDateValue = "Fri, 27 Aug 2010 22:00:07 +0000";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +ffff", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The above works fine, as far as that it will not throw an exception.

I am assuming that the `+0000` at the end of the string is supposed to be a timezone specifier. If so, the `ffff` is incorrect, as it stands for `The hundred thousandths of a second`, not the timezone specifier, which is `K`. If it is indeed supposed to be the timezone specifier, then this would be the correct code:

```
string MyDateValue = "Fri, 27 Aug 2010 22:00:07 +0000";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss K", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

See [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Should your `YYYY` be `yyyy`?

My help file for the custom formatting information for DateTime only has lowercase y's, no uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the change in year: YYYY->yyyy

```
DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +ffff", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateValue, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The year part needs to be lower-case: `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +ffff`

Answer (score -1):

I dropped the "+0000" and just used `DateTime.Parse()`

To get to my actual timezone (since +0000 is probably an offset from GMT)  I set that as well.

```
string myDateValue = "Fri, 27 Aug 2010 22:00:07"; //get this using substring
int gmtOffset = -6; //I'm in the Central TimeZone
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(myDateValue);
dt.AddHours(gmtOffset);

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: GMT offset is dependant on DLS