# DateTime parsing complicated strings C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse date-strings to DateTime objects with the following format:

> Tue, 30 Oct 2012 09:51:20 +0000

What I have tried so far is many different variants with DateTime.ParseExact().

I have tried:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon, 29 Oct 2012 12:13:51 +0000", 
                    "ddd, dd MM yyyy hh':'mm':'ss zzz", 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With thousands different formats as second parameter, using null instead of InvarantCulture as third parameter etc etc. I can't get it to work. How should I parse a string like this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
var s = "Tue, 30 Oct 2012 09:51:20 +0000";
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

---

The month (`Oct`) is actually `MMM`, not `MM`, and the time (`09:51:20`) should be `hh:mm:ss` instead of `hh':'mm':'ss`.

Comment: Note that you may want to use `HH` instead of `hh` if you want to use a 24h clock instead of a 12h clock.

Comment: Also, depending on the [`DateTimeKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) you're interested in, have a look at the difference of [`zzz`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) and [`K`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#KSpecifier)

Answer (score 2):

The correct parsing is

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon, 29 Oct 2012 12:13:51 +0000", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601636/parsing-a-strangely-formatted-datetime-anyone-fancy-stepping-up)